# Showing UIImageView on startup after a delay with close button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I want to show a UIImageView after 3 seconds from the view did load. This image view is kind of a static Ad, a static image loaded that will show up when the application starts as mentioned. This ismageView should have a close button on it so the user can close it just like the typical ad behavior. It's my first time dealing with this kind of situations so please help me out i'm totally lost.

Till now i got to animate a view containing an image view with fade in and out animations, which is perfect..but now haw can i add a close button to it, to make her dismiss only when that button is pressed? this is my code

```
UIImageView *wnn = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
wnn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 300, 300);
[wnn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu-icon.png"]];
UIView *jn = [[UIView alloc]init];
[jn addSubview:wnn];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview: jn];
[jn setAlpha:0.f];

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.f delay:0.f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
    [jn setAlpha:1.f];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.f delay:0.f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        [jn setAlpha:0.f];
    } completion:nil];
}];
```

Comment: which ads you are showing?

Comment: i have a static image Ad to show @Arvind-Systematix , how can i do it ?

Comment: Is there iAd or custom UIImageview showing as Ad? that you want to show with close button?

Comment: @Arvind-Systematix i want to create from scratch a uiimageview containing that image, loading after 3 seconds with a close button that when pressed dismisses her…how can i do it

Comment: Have you tried with NSTimer?

Comment: @Arvind-Systematix i need to add a close button when pressed dismisses the view..that's my main problem

Comment: Just create a UIButton (`[UIButton buttonWithType:...]`) and add it to the container view (jn)  I'd also strongly recommend adding the views to self.view and not self.navigationController.view.  Generally speaking it's a bad idea to add views to somebody else's view controller.

Comment: @David i'm really new at Xcode, can you please show me how i searched to whole internet and on the edge of collapsing :S

Answer (score 1):

You can follow below steps:

1. Open Storyboard file with your viewcontroller.
2. Place UIView from library to your main view of viewcontroller.
3. Place your image and close button on new UIview placed.
4. Now set IBOutlet for this uiview.
5. Make hide/show this view instead of image and close button in your method.